# how to get List<String> of value from key:value return by mongo in java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Mongo crud repository in java spring boot project, for entity like id:"1",id:"2",id:"3", I want to return List of String like ["1","2","3"]
I am using findAllById and response is {id:1,id:2,id:3} I converted it into ["1","2","3"] by using loop and then return list.

```
for(Entity entity:entity.findAllById()) {
        list.add(store.getId());
    }
```

is this possible without using this loop I can do the same and return string list .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.collections4.IterableUtils.toList(repo.findAllById(ids)). stream().map(Entity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Note the IterableUtils.toList has a loop :)

Comment: Worked!! Thanks @ShaharT I was looking for something like this only.